# adjective phrases or relative clauses

Tags: adjectives, relative-clauses

What’s the difference between adjective phrases and relative clauses.

> The dog covered in mud ...
>
> The dog, which was covered in mud ...

What’s the difference? Which one should I use?

Comment: It relies on more context. what's the rest of your sentence?

Comment: The first is a participial phrase with a passive participle, NOT a relative clause or an adjective phrase. (Cue BillJ, disagreeing with me in this)

Comment: I agree with Scrooble, except that I take "covered in mud" as a past participial clause, not a phrase. There are differences, of course: in your first example the clause "covered in mud" is a modifier -- it modifies "dog", but in the second "which was covered in mud" is a supplementary (non-defining) relative clause and such clauses are not modifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'relative clause' is an 'adjective clause'.

"The dog [that was] covered in mud jumped on the bed" uses a restrictive phrase in which the relative pronoun is elided.

"The dog, [which was] covered in mud, jumped on the bed" uses a non-restrictive (adverbial) phrase.

When the relative clause is 'traced' on its subject, and uses a copula (form of 'to be'), then the pronoun and verb can be elided (omitted).